# Oauth2 authorization using google as provider

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

My frontend is Angular and backend is spring micoservice using spring security.
I need to use oauth2 authorization using facebook.
From Angular I am using "http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/facebook" to get the authorization endpoint and getting the code and state successfully.
Now I need to get the token from facebook. I tried to use "http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/facebook" as the token endpoint and providing the code and state as parameters. But its throwing error.

"http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/facebook?code=XXXXX&state=YYYYY" is not giving proper response in my spring security backend.

```
application properties :
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.facebook.clientId =  
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.facebook.clientSecret = 
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.facebook.redirectUri:
```

My spring backend is on 8080.

Is my token endpoint correct ? Any mistake I am doing here , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I added a new redirect uri in google dev console and it got resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).